# openni_ros vs openni_kinect

Tags: kinect, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the difference between the ros-diamondback-openni-ros and ros-diamondback-openni-kinect ubuntu packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9753/openni_ros-vs-openni_kinect/) by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 544 on 2011-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The difference is that you want to install the -kinect one, not the -ros one (see this [thread](http://kinect-with-ros.976505.n3.nabble.com/Ros-kinect-Install-openni-kinect-or-openni-ros-td2666766.html)). I'm not sure why there are two or why the -ros one hasn't been removed from the package list, though.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-04-19**:
Use openni_kinect  the stack openni_ros one was temporarily there and so as not to break people's checkouts it has not been removed.  It will be removed in the near future.